# Customizing spinner's item background color

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am making an app to calculate resistor value out of its color bands. Everything works fine on the pure programming side. At the moment for selcting color bands I am using a spinner filled with list of colors.

I really want to make it look better. I want to be able to set background color of each item in the spinner to its corresponding color:

[image]

What should I do to achive this? Here is part of my code:

**Array used for spinner:**

```
  <string-array name="FourBandResistorFullColor">
    <item>Black</item>
    <item>Brown</item>
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Violet</item>
    <item>Gray</item>
    <item>White</item>    
  </string-array>
```

**Adapter code in `OnCreate` method:**

```
    var bandOne = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.bandOneColor);
    var bandOneAdapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.FourBandResistorFullColor,
                                                         Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
    bandOneAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    bandOne.Adapter = bandOneAdapter;
    bandOne.ItemSelected += BandOne_ItemSelected;
```

Comment: What adapter do you use for the `Spinner`?

Comment: I Updated the question with some code!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a custom adapter. I guess you are using an ArrayAdapter? If so you could do it like so:

```
    private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId); 
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            int color = getColorFromName(getItem(position));
            view.setBackgroundColor(color);
            return view;
        }   
    }
```

Note that `getColorFromName` is a function you would need to implement yourself. It maps from String to an int color value (ARGB). Red for exmaple would be 0xffff0000.

Comment: Thanks, But what I ment is that items in the spinner should have background colors corresponding to the item name for sake of ease of use.

Comment: that's exactly what the code does. The child views of the spinner get created in getView(). And by calling setBackgroundColor you achieve what you want. The only (minor) problem is that setBackgroundColors takes an int. (4 Bytes. 1>Alpha 2>Red 3>Green 4>Blue). So you need to write a mapping function for converting the names to those ints.

Comment: O Ok, sorry I am terrible at Java...no idea what this could would do :P I'll try to port this to C# then.

Comment: i did not realize that you need the code in c#. But by lookin at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121581/custom-arrayadapter-with-custom-filter) i know that it should'nt be to hard to create a custom arrayadapter in c#.