# Java Android Spinner Item Background Color

Tags: java, android, background, spinner, android-spinner

I want to change the color of an item in a string array / Spinner, but I can't get it to work.

I also found this topic and it seems to be the thing I need:
[Customizing spinner's item background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374675/customizing-spinners-item-background-color)

I tried to implement it (not just copy paste) but it didn't work.

Can someone help me maybe how to implement it the "right way" (I'm not that experienced in Android/Java)

Can't I just do something (easier) like this?

```
<string-array name="test">
   <item android:backgroundcolor="#08FF00">green</item>
   <item android:backgroundcolor="#FF0000">red</item>
</string-array>
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The "custom adapter" solution is the correct one. What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: i get a lot of errors .. like "var" can not be resolved to be a variable.. is that maybe because the guy wrote it for C#? .. example of the errors: [link](http://imgur.com/Bhn0r4p)

Comment: The snippet in the question looks like Xamarin, but the answer is Java. You should use that, it works.

Comment: ok, i see.. i could implement the code snipplet now, but of course i have no functionality for the method "getColorFromName" .. can you help me with this?  I only have little java/android experience... I know what i have to do (get the name from the selected spinner item and i.e. if it is "black" i convert it to #000000 ..) but i don't know how to do this .. in PHP I would have no problems with this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter from [Customizing spinner's item background color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374756/82788) is precisely what you need. Of course, you need to implement a method returning the desired color for each item of the array.

If your input is the color name (i.e., this spinner acts a color picker, you could use [Color.parseColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29). It supports some named colors, plus numeric values.

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the
>   string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception.
>   Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green',
>   'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray',
>   'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuschia',
>   'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'